# difference between $(function (){}) and (function ($){})

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am very confused about whats the actual meaning of

```
(function ($){})(jQuery) 
//in plugin
```

and

```
$(function (){})
//in page.
```

Please clearify me on this.

Comment: The first executes immediately and passes jQuery to the function, the second waits until the DOM is ready.

Comment: I am new to jquery , please tell what do mean by -passes jQuery to the function ??

Comment: $(function(){}); -> $(document).ready(function(){});.  Both are same.       Where as, (function($){ .... })(jQuery); is the structure for writing  plugins.

Comment: @adeneo You should have answered rather than commented ;)

Comment: ok ,(function($){ .... })(jQuery); is a structure but what it actually means as in terms of what does this structure do.

Comment: It defines a function `function($){ .... }`, calls it immediately and passes `jQuery` to it, i.e. inside the function `$` refers to `jQuery`. This is done because the global `$` might not refer to `jQuery` when you include other libraries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
(function ($){})(jQuery)
```

...is a function being defined and then immediately called, with the JQuery object passed in as an argument. The `$` is a reference to JQuery which you can then use inside the function. It's equivilent to this:

```
var myFunc = function ($){};
myFunc(jQuery);
```

This:

```
$(function (){})
```

...is a call *to* JQuery, passing in a function which it should execute once the document has finished loading.

Comment: Thanks I m clear know. Only thing which i didnt get is why to pass jQuery in myFunc as myFunc(jQuery)

Comment: To be honest I'm guessing, but it may partly be that doing it this way makes the function declare its dependencies in its argument list instead of relying on global variables. It's known as a [self-invoking function](http://sarfraznawaz.wordpress.com/2012/01/26/javascript-self-invoking-functions/).

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){}); === $(document).ready(function(){});.
```

Both the above are same.

Where as, `(function($){ .... })(jQuery);` is the structure for writing plugins.

Comment: ok ,(function($){ .... })(jQuery); is a structure but what it actually means as in terms of what does this structure do.

Comment: @sathish: check out the actual anaswer

Comment: @InternalServerError Hi, i clearly mentioned, $(function(){}); and $(document).ready(function(){}); are same...     not (function($){ .... })(jQuery)...

Comment: (function($){ .... })(jQuery); is the structure for writing plugins. And It also acts like wrapper around our function to avoid conflict.  If we want to write our own plugins, we can write like, $.fn.extend( ..

Answer (score 0):

Those two are not the same.The following will explain every thing clearly,

```
(function($){
  /* code here runs instantly*/
  $('document').ready(function(){ // this function is exactly the same as the one below
        /* code here runs when dom is ready */
  });
  $(function(){ // this function is exactly the same as the one above.
        /* code here runs when dom is ready */
  }
)(jQuery); // jQuery is a parameter of function($) {}
```

Reference: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/what-s-the-difference-between-function-code-jquery-and-document-ready-function-code

Comment: What does function($){} means?

Comment: can we write ready function inside "(function($){" ??. I think, its not needed.

Comment: it's just explain the difference betwween the methods.the description is within /* */